# ASP Gridview drop down list selection changed, how to fill a dropdown list other than in rowDataBound()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a `gridview` in ASP, having `template Fields` containing `select`, `edit` and `delete` links each row, and the footer containing `insert` link.

There are two `dropdownlists` in each row, let's say: `Category` and `sub-category`, when I change the contents of `category DropDownList` the `sub-category DropDownList` should automatically display the corresponding contents.

I've tried to write a `onSelectedIndexChanged` handler, but I don't know how to continue. **Any Ideas?**  *(bearing in mind that I did all the rowDataBound() codes to fill the Drop down lists)*

**In other words, how to populate a dropdownlist other than in row_databound()**

code:

```
protected void grdBulkScheduler_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {   
                DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCategory");
                if (ddlCategory != null)
                {
                    ddlCategory .DataSource = cData.GetCategory();
                    ddlCategory .DataValueField = "c_ID";
                    ddlCategory .DataTextField = "c_Text";
                    ddlCategory .DataBind();                    
                }
```

Here I am finding the drop down list **category** from **GridViewRowEventArgs**

**in the selectedIndexChanged handler, how can I find the DropDownList?** *since
                    `DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCategory")` is not working*

Comment: Did you add the onSelectedIndexChanged event on the DropDownList?
or you just created it in c#?

Comment: I added it, and it is been read by the compiler, but then I am stuck, I dunno how to continue,

Comment: Why stuck? In that function, bind the other dropdownlist; get the elements you need and do a bind();

Comment: Ohhh I get it, its IN the row! So where did you create the event handler??

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1313185.aspx/1
Here you have something similar, hope it helps

Comment: So what do you want to put in the drop down list, I dont see where is the problem

Comment: Well and where are you putting the event handler?? are you sure the event handler is being called??
Do you have runat="server" in the DDL?

Comment: in the selectedIndexChanged handler, how can I find the DropDownList? use `DropDownList ddlCategory = sender as DropDownList;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to bind data to the subcategory dropdownlist using the value you have selected in the category dropdownlist. You can do:

```
protected void ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.Parent;
    DropDownList ddlSubCategory = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlSubCategory");
    ddlSubCategory.DataSource = //whatever you want to bind, e.g. based on the selected value, using((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
    ddlSubCategory.DataBind();
}
```

If I have misunderstood you, please correct me in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

FindControl is not recursive and you have a number of `TableCell` controls in the `Cells` property on your `GridViewRow` before you get to the level where your control is, so changing it to something like this will work:

```
TableCell cell = (TableCell)e.Row.FindControl("idOfMyCellIfItHasOne");
DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)cell.FindControl("ddlCategory");
```

Alternatively, if your cell/column has no ID and/or you know the position of the cell in the table isn't going to change, you can use the indexer on the `Cells` property:

```
DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].FindControl("ddlCategory");
```

Answer (score 0):

use in your dropdown  **AutoPostBack="true"**

like that:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="footer_id"  AutoPostBack="true" 
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="footer_id_SelectedIndexChanged" 
 runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```